# How to detect if 'new page' has been loaded in the admin panel

Tags: wordpress

This is what I would like to achieve in wordpress

When a new post is created (i.e. when you click on 'new post') and the blank form is loaded in the admin panel I would like to automatically create 2 custom fields and give them default values. However the user can overwrite these values and save them. Then when the user edits the again wordpress simply dispays the custom vaues for the post as it normally would

In order to do this I am guessing I need to know how to detect when the create new post button has been clicked (as opposed to edit post) and then add 2 custom fields to the admin panel display.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give. I am new to wordpress and the way it saves posts and autosaves  and creates a post before it has been published as a draft is confusing to say the least to the uninitiated.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following code in your *functions.php* file, replacing `Field Name X` and `Field Value X` by the actual values you want.

```
function set_default_custom_fields( $post_id ) {
    if ( $_GET['post_type'] == 'post' ) {
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'Field Name 1', 'Field Value 1', true );
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'Field Name 2', 'Field Value 2', true );
    }
    return true;
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'set_default_custom_fields' );
```

And take a look at the docs of the function **[add_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta)** and the hook **[wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post)**.

---

Anyway, I suggest you to use the fantastic free plugin [**Advanced Custom Fields**](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). It allows you to define the custom fields you want among many different field types (text, wysiwyg, image, checkbox, etc.), and associate them to all posts. You can also give them a default value and much more!